# Change initial position and rotation of a model

Tags: html, 3d, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

Got a simple .html file using A-Frame that loads a specific model.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Octant Cube - by Dodds, H. & Peres, T.</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Present in the Taxonomy article">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA">
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="octant" src="octant.glb"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      <a-entity gltf-model="#octant"></a-entity>
  </body>
</html>
```

The object loads fine on the page ([as the documentation suggests](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/gltf-model.html#example)) but this is what I see at first

[image: WebVR A-Frame not satisfied]

If I look all down I'm able to see one plane

[image: Look down to see a plane]

But would like to see the following at start

[image: Ideal start A-Frame]

Using the A-Frame Inspector I was able to see this would suit nice in the position 0 , 0.347, -3 and rotation 0, 58.0274, -0.27.

[image: A-Frame Inspector]

I tried adding the position and rotation to `<a-assets>` and `<a-asset-item ... >` but no change was possible to be seen.

How can I change the initial position and the rotation of the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to add that information in `<a-entity>` instead, like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Octant Cube - by Dodds, H. & Peres, T.</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Present in the Taxonomy article">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA">
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="octant" src="octant.glb"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      <a-entity position="0 0.347 -4" rotation="0 60 -1"  gltf-model="#octant"></a-entity>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the final result

[image: Final Octant Taxonomy]